# Facebook Ads API AdSet Creation Normalization Error

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ads-api

I'm getting an odd error from the Facebook ADs API. Sending the following payload:

```
{
  "campaign_group_id": "54321",
  "bid_type": "ABSOLUTE_OCPM",
  "name": "Hello AdCampaign",
  "bid_info": {
    "ACTIONS": 1
  },
  "targeting": {
    "behaviors": [
      {
        "name": "BEHAVIOR NAME",
        "id": 12345
      }
    ],
    "geo_locations": {
      "countries": [
        "US"
      ]
    },
    "page_types": "feed"
  },
  "campaign_status": "ACTIVE",
  "daily_budget": 100
}
```

Providing this payload to the ads api is returning the following error message:

*You are requesting a transaction which requires the adgroups to be normalized, but normalize failed because Normalization expects a collection*

Which has an associated error code of **1487079** which.. I cannot find documentation for.. ANYWHERE.

This will work, if I remove the **behaviors** attribute of targeting.. but of course that isn't desirable. So it's something to do with the behaviors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per [the docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ads-api/adset/v2.2), I believe `page_types` should be a list. Try this:

```
{
    ...
    "page_types": ["feed"],
    ...
}
```

Comment: What an insane error.. completely unrelated and undocumented error message! Thanks Craig!

Comment: I find that if I try to replicate a request in the Graph API Explorer that I can see two error codes. 1487079 sounds like what I've seen referred to in the response as a "suberror" code. The Graph API Explorer will show a main response error code which is often documented at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ads-api/error-reference/